# C Array of Structures of array of structures

Tags: c

Proceeding with my project which should use a quite complex structures, I felt in a dighole. I need to declare an array of structures (Menus) each one contains an array of structures (Elements).
In Visual Basic, from which I come, it will be (simplified):

```
type t_element
  elementID as long
  size as long
  color as long
end type

Type t_Menu
  menuID as long
  numElements as long
  elements() as t_element 
end type

Dim Menus(10) as t_menu
Redim Menus(1).elements(5)
```

I tried something similar in XC8 with:

```
typedef struct t_element
{
    char eleID;
    int size;
    int color; 
}Element;

typedef struct t_Menu
{
    char IDmenu;
    char elementNumber;
    Element elements[];
}Menus;
```

Hoping that this is feasable, how can I declare the array of Element inside the Menus ?

This does not work:

```
Menus Menu[10];   //this is OK
Element Menu[1].elements[5];  //this is not
Menu[1].(Element)elements[5]; //this is not
```

There is a solution? If yes, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `Element e = Menu[1].elements[5];` ?

Comment: `Element elements[];` -> `Element *elements;` and use memory management functions if your system supports them.

Comment: @MikeCAT: `elements[]` is a flexible array member and perfectly valid and the best approach if using dynamic allocation. No need for the extra indirection. That only complicates things even more.

Comment: If you know the max number of elements in a menu at compile time and it is a reasonably small value then you can provide that size in the structure definition, e.g., Element elements[10]; and then access that via Menu[1].elements[5];

Comment: @Olaf I don't think it is valid here because `Menus` with flexible array member is used as elements of array. References: [DCL38-C. Use the correct syntax when declaring a flexible array member - CERT C Coding Standard - CERT Secure Coding Standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member) and [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.7.2.1, paragraph 3 (I didn't notice " if using dynamic allocation")

Comment: @MikeCAT: Yes, I noticed that later. So it is either a `Menus *m[]` or what you propose. OTOH there is noting in the description OP cannot use arrays with fixed length. (BTW. coding standards are not authoritative. The only resource from your list which is is the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the access to the elements of the structures:

```
typedef struct t_element
{
    char eleID;
    int size;
    int color; 
}Element;

typedef struct t_Menu
{
    char IDmenu;
    char elementNumber;
    Element elements[100];
}Menus;

int main() 
{
    Menus menus[20];
    Element element1; 

    menus[5].elements[3].color = 1;
    menus[5].elements[3].size = 2;
    menus[5].elements[3].eleID ='a';
    menus[5].elementNumber = 1;

    element1 = menus[5].elements[3];
    int color = element1.color;  

   printf("color for menus[5].elements[3]=%d",color); 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually declaring a fix (maximum) number of sub elements inside the Menu structure was the answer and I already did it; unfortunately I missed a semicolon in a row and this raised so many errors that I did not notice the original problem.